# DATEVALUE function returning date not result in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

Using google sheets and this function `=DATEVALUE("9/7/2016")` and expecting a number to be returned in the cell but it just shows `9/7/2016`

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

If your cell is formatted as a `DATE` type then switch it to automatic or if you don't want to change the formatting you can wrap your formula with:

`=TEXT(VALUE("9/7/2016"),"#")`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the cell format as Date, change it to Number

Go to the Format menu, choose the Number option then select Number from the sub-menu